# Ubuntu Netbook Remix-like Linux distros?

Tags: linux, virtualbox, linux-distributions

I just downloaded Virtualbox to satisfy my need to mess around with every linux distro I can find without butchering my computer. Can anyone recommend a couple distros with interfaces similar to the Ubuntu Netbook Remix? Ideally I'd like to use UNR, but VB can't seem to mount .img files. Also, can anyone recommend a good place to search for things like this that isn't Distrowatch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_Netbook_Remix) has a link to [a list in "see also" section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Netbook_Distributions).
Look at [Eeebuntu](http://www.eeebuntu.org/) or [Easy Peasy](http://www.geteasypeasy.com/).

Answer (score 0):

I would look into [JeOS (Just Enough Operating System)](http://www.ubuntu.com/products/whatisubuntu/serveredition/jeos), an Ubuntu server variant focused on getting just enough Ubuntu on a system to be functional that you can build up from.

As for keeping up with these things, there's a few places where Ubuntu announcements are made.

- [Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+announcements)
- [Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/forumdisplay.php?f=13)
- [Mailing list](https://lists.ubuntu.com/mailman/listinfo/ubuntu-announce)

For other Linux distributions, there's a plethora of technical blogs and the like that often share the new cool thing, such as Ars and Lifehacker.

Answer (score 0):

How about the new version of the UNR karmic koala is available as an iso file. It's only in alpha but I'm using it on an aspire one and its*reasonably* reliable

http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/karmic/alpha-4/

Answer (score 0):

I was using Eeebuntu for a while. I liked it, although I preferred Ubbuntu Netbook remix. My only change was for the actual environment, as I prefer the standard display of the environment, instead of the Netbook-Like display. This is mostly because I use Ubuntu as my main desktop at home.